# Detecting X session in a bash script (.bashrc etc.)

Tags: bash, xorg, environment-variables

Recently I put `xset b off` to my .bashrc.  Now I'm annoyed by the error thet pops up when I log in via tty or via ssh, i.e. outside X session.

First thing that came in my mind was `[[ -z "$SOME_VAR" ]] && xset b off` (well, turns out that testing [variable being set vs. being empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/bash-test-for-a-variable-unset-using-a-function) is a different question).  But which SOME_VAR is the correct one?

So I diffed tty's `set` output and urxvt's `set` output to see which variables are set in X and missing in tty.  As expected, there were quite many differences (listing only those that seemed relevant to me):

- `DESKTOP_SESSION`
- `DISPLAY`
- `GDMSESSION`
- `SESSION_MANAGER`
- `WINDOWID`
- `WINDOWPATH`
- `XAUTHORITY`
- `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE`
- `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`
- `XDG_DATA_DIRS`
- `XDG_MENU_PREFIX`

Which one is the most correct and universal one to test in order to detect if I'm in an X session or not?  Something that would work across as many distros and platforms and desktop environments as possible?

Or is there even better way than testing environment variables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple and effective way to test that your display server is available and valid is to test it with `xhost`.  You can't always rely on checking for a value in the `DISPLAY` variable since it could be set with an invalid value.

```
if xhost >& /dev/null ; then echo "Display exists"
else echo "Display invalid" ; fi
```

The reason I do this is because I run several scripts in my user `crontab` that operate on the display when it exists, but work differently when not.  At the top of my `crontab`, I set the `DISPLAY` variable to `:0` even though it doesn't exist yet.  Scripts in the `crontab` that start with `@reboot` will start regardless of whether you have a display or not.  This will allow you to dynamically detect when your display comes and goes within the same script.

NOTE: The `>&` only works in `bash` >= 4.  Otherwise use `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Nice, tested also with `ssh -X`; works fine!

Answer (score 15):

I think checking `DISPLAY` would be the best approach.

- It handles remote logins (e.g. ssh -X).
- It is available in most - if not all - platforms.
- It is independent of window manager/DE.

Comment: I'd also go for `DISPLAY`, or simply suppress the error message in general. Give `/dev/null` some love from time to time.

Comment: @frostschutz No, I'm trying to run only relevant part of script.  Suppressing error messages does not make any step in that direction.  In fact, it can lead to serious confusion troubleshooting *other* things that might potentially break.

Comment: I started using this approach shortly after the answer, and it worked perfectly with simple `ssh`s until now, when I started doing `ssh -X`---to be able to use Vim over ssh so that content selected by visual mode gets to local X clipboard, for which *you don't need xserver* on the server side.  So DISPLAY gets set just as effect of simply enabling the forwarding, even if xserver and xset are not present.

Comment: That would be then: [`if [[ $DISPLAY ]]; then … fi`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398491/39845)

Comment: Your `DISPLAY` variable can point to a display that doesn't actually have an X server running (for example when it is hardcoded in a script, or the X server was shut down after the variable was set).

Answer (score 6):

I usually use the `TERM` variable to test for X in my scripts.

`TERM` is usually set to `linux` on TTY and `xterm` on X.
I use the word "usually" here, since applications like GNU Screen and TMux seem to mess with the `TERM` Variable.

Comment: try `echo $TERM` to find out the richt setting on your mashine in different consoles. I use `[ $TERM == "linux" ] && echo do some stuff` on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

This should work perfectly well:

```
[ ! -t 0 ] && xset b off
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

```
-t

    file (descriptor) is associated with a terminal device

    This test option may be used to check whether the stdin [ -t 0 ] 
    or stdout [ -t 1 ] in a given script is a terminal.
```

So, when this evaluates to false (`[ ! -t 0 ]`) we are in a GUI environment.

Comment: With this, I get the same result in both X and in the console, namely `[ -t 0 ]` and `[ -t 1 ]` are both true.

Comment: Strange, it works for me when sshing into a remote host.

Comment: `[ -t 0 ]` works fine on the console in Ubuntu (using CTRL ALT F1)

Answer (score 1):

### In an ordinary bash script: `if [[ $DISPLAY ]]`

On the same computer, `$DISPLAY` will return for example `0:0` in a terminal emulator, but nothing in a real terminal.
This can easily be tested with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> versus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.

A `bash` condition based on `$DISPLAY` would look as follows:

```bsh
if [[ $DISPLAY ]]; then 
  …
fi
```

### In `.profile` or `.personal`: `if xhost >& /dev/null`

From my experience, `$DISPLAY` is not yet set when `.profile`, or by extension, `.personal` are executed. For those cases, the [answer by user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338862/39845) [`cmevoli`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338862/39845) serves best:

```bsh
if xhost >& /dev/null; then
fi
```

I ran into this problem when defining a desktop [<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434143/39845) [key mapping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434143/39845) that should not apply to my server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do that.

In bash, try

```
function xruns {
    if [[ `pstree -As $$ | grep xinit | wc -l` == 1 ]]; then
        echo "You are in X."
    else
        echo "You are not in X."
    fi
}
```

Or, in zsh, try

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

CURRENT_VT=`tty`

if [[ ${CURRENT_VT[6]} == "p" ]];        # or `${CURRENT_VT:5:1}` in bash
then
   # X stuff
else 
   # non-X stuff      
fi
```

Comment: Point taken, but do you test your code before posting?  The first one has syntax error and does not actualy detect if *we are* in X session so it will `echo 1` if X is running and you log in via tty1-6 or ssh. The other one always does "non-X stuff"--I think that `${CURRENT_VT[6]}` means rather 6th line than 6th char.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Aha, my stuff doesn't work in bash (I use zsh). Didn't think of that. Well, you could try it in zsh (type `zsh`) and possibly do some modifications if you like it, to make it work in bash.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: OK, I changed it. As for the "log in via tty1-6", as it happens, that's what I do, and then I use the second solution (above) and set a variable. Check out [this](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/conf/.zshrc) `.zshrc` and search for `export VT`. I use the variable to hold what Linux VT/console/tty I'm in (for the zsh prompt) but in X, I just set it to "X" (although not a VT). But that's details, you could work it out any way you'd like in bash using the same principle.

Comment: I have added bash version of the condition to the second example.  However, I think that the first one is still wrong.  Maybe having ps print *only ancestors* would help.  I'm not sure if it's possible, though.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Check out the edit. That does it for me, including the tty stuff.