# git: use visual diff (meld) only when in GUI

Tags: git, diff

I know I can specify external diff command to be used for `git diff`:

```
[diff]
    external =
```

But then when I am logged in console (without X) this fails because my visual diff cannot open display (obviously)

How can I tell git to only use visual diff only when logged in GUI/X ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754762/can-gitconfig-options-be-set-conditionally for info on doing conditional configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for `an answer drawing from credible and/or official
sources` so I'm going to cite some official documentation in this
answer.

First, we need to find a way to determine if we're running inside `X`
session.  We could do that for example by checking if `$DISPLAY`
variable is set.  As it's described in `man X`:

> DISPLAY
>
> This is the only mandatory environment variable. It must
>          point to an X server. See section "Display Names" above.

However, it might not be a good idea because someone could just set
`DISPLAY` to a fake value even outside of `X`.  A better way is
suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338862/72304):

```
if xhost >& /dev/null ; then echo "Display exists"
else echo "Display invalid" ; fi
```

You should have a program named `xhost` already installed on your
machine, make sure you have it:

```
$ type -a xhost
xhost is /usr/bin/xhost
```

Now, we could just set `diff.external` to point to a wrapper that
would call an external diff if we're inside `X` and run the default
`git diff` mechanism if we're not inside `X`.  Unfortunately I'm not
able to come up with a simple way to run a default `git diff` in
`diff.external` so let's instead create an alias for `git` that would
set `diff.external` temporarily using `-c`.  As described in `man git`:

> -c < name>=< value>
>
> Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will override values from configuration
>              files. The  is expected in the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).
>
> Note that omitting the = in git -c foo.bar ...  is allowed and sets foo.bar to the boolean true value
>              (just like [foo]bar would in a config file). Including the equals but with an empty value (like git -c
>              foo.bar= ...) sets foo.bar to the empty string.

It would be something like:

```
$ git -c diff.external=diff-wrapper.sh ...
```

To sum up:

- Create a script called `~/git-wrapper.sh` and replace
  `<YOUR_DIFF_WRAPPER>` with whatever you wish:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env sh

  if xhost >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
      git -c diff.external=<YOUR_DIFF_WRAPPER>  "$@"
  else
      git "$@"
  fi
  ```
- Set an executable bit:

  ```
   $ chmod +x ~/git-wrapper.sh
  ```
- Set alias in your shell startup file, for example `~/.bashrc` and reload shell:

  ```
   alias git=~/git-wrapper.sh
  ```
- Use `git` normally:

  ```
   $ git diff
  ```

  It will use `<YOUR_DIFF_WRAPPER>` if you're inside `X` and will use
  default `git-diff` outside of `X`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several simpleminded ways to accomplish this... to do it "outside" git, you can set your difftool program (you probably want difftool instead of diff for launching a visual diff) to a wrapper script which figures out whether you're in a graphical environment or not and launches the appropriate program; or "inside" git, you can do some environment-specific conditional include (includeIf).